# How to setup protobuf in kotlin/android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers

First time using protobuf, so following googles instructions I placed all my .protos in a protos folder in my android studio project. I know the .proto files are setup correctly. I compile the files from that folder using:

```
protoc -I=. --java_out=. --kotlin_out=. filename.proto
```

This generates a bunch of kotlin and java files that look like what I am supposed to get. However, android studio throws a ton of errors and doesn't seem to like most of the code in those files.

So my question is there something additional I need to do with the setup, bring in a dependency in the gradle file? I saw an example like that but it seemed only relevant to the plugin for compiling using gradle - since I'm compiling from the command line I don't think I should need that?

Answer (score 8):

One cannot add `*.proto` files into Java or Kotlin source directories ...
For Android use `protobuf-lite`; the configuration looks about like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.18' apply false
}
```

Module `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.protobuf'
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
            }
            kotlin {
                srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/main/kotlin'
            }
            proto {
                srcDir 'src/main/proto' // default value
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.20.1'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin-lite:3.20.1'
}
```

There's also a `protoc` compiler and `protoc-gen-javalite` generator available:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.20.1'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            java {
                option 'lite'
            }
            kotlin {
                option 'lite'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also see [`protobuf-gradle-plugin`](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) (the Kotlin/GRPC example there isn't for Android).

Comment: eg. Firebase is using `protobuf-javalite`, which may subsequently lead to a dependency conflict. Android Java is not necessarily the same as "Java". `option 'lite'` is also a matter of performance. That Kotlin example on GitHub is the anti-pattern, which not to follow on Android. You don't get to choose.

Comment: I tried this and I get 

```> Could not find method option() for arguments [lite] on extension 'kotlin' of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinAndroidProjectExtension.
```

I'm using gradle 7.4, Any idea?

Comment: @Michael I am also using the Kotlin DSL and [tonycodes reply on this github issue](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/518) helped me.

Comment: @MartinZeitler This post really helped me understand when to use the `lite` dependencies. Declaring sourceSets is not necessary since you are using the default location for proto files. Documented in the plugin docs: https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin

Comment: @Michael use task.builtins { } and put the java or kotlin inside that

Answer (score 0):

I configured protobuf like this:

**app/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.4"
}

android {}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.18.0")
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.19.4"
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().configureEach {
            builtins {
                id("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```