# Setting up Protobuf + Kotlin in Android Studio 2023

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers

I spend hours on just setting up Protobuf with Kotlin in Android Studio. The endgoal is just that my proto files are compiled in Kotlin and that I can use them in my project.

I have an example project here: https://github.com/Jasperav/ProtobufAndroid. It mimics my setup in the real application: an external dir containing the proto files and the android project. It contains all the code mentioned below. This is a combined effort of tutorials I found on the internet. It is probably terrible wrong. I tried https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin, but it just looks so complicated for something simple I am doing:

- Have a dir with protofiles somewhere on your filesystem
- Create a new Android project on Kotlin
- In the Project build.gradle, add `id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.9.2' apply false` as plugin
- In the Module build.gradle, add ->

1. This to the dependencies: `implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.21.12'`
2. The `sourceSets` at the bottom inside the `android` bracket
3. The `protobuf` section at the bottom between the `dependencies` and `android` section.

**sourceSets:**

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/main/kotlin'
        }
        proto {
            srcDir '/Users/me/androidkotlin/proto'
        }
    }
}
```

**protobuf:**

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.21.12'
    }
    plugins {
        kotlinlite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-kotlin:3.21.12'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main").forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                getByName("kotlin") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method proto() for arguments [build_cxwfo79b6zcc266x9rsqzou9f$_run_closure1$_closure8$_closure10$_closure12@203aac02] on source set main of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in a good way, but, there is some stuff missing:

The gradle code I'll share is written in Kotlin, just in case. If you can convert your grade files to Kotlin, nice, if not you have to convert them to groovy.

1. The first thing to check is if you have the `proto` folder in the right path, it should be in

```
root->app->src->main->proto
```

2. In the project gradle make sure to have the plugin applied

```
id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.15" apply false
```

3. In the app gradle, make sure to have the following.

```
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.protobuf")
}
```

The dependencies:

```
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.2")
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:3.21.2")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.52.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.52.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.52.0")

    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.21.7")
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:3.21.2")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:1.3.0")
```

And the protobuf task:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${rootProject.ext["protobufVersion"]}"
    }
    plugins {
        id("java") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${rootProject.ext["grpcVersion"]}"
        }
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${rootProject.ext["grpcVersion"]}"
        }
        id("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:${rootProject.ext["grpcKotlinVersion"]}:jdk8@jar"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach {
            it.plugins {
                id("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
                id("grpc") {
                    option("lite")
                }
                id("grpckt") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
            it.builtins {
                id("kotlin") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the versions I'm using:

```
ext["grpcVersion"] = "1.47.0"
ext["grpcKotlinVersion"] = "1.3.0" // CURRENT_GRPC_KOTLIN_VERSION
ext["protobufVersion"] = "3.21.2"
ext["coroutinesVersion"] = "1.6.2"
```

Having that your project should generate the code based on your proto files.

For further reference, I recently build this Android App based on Kotlin + gRPC: https://github.com/wilsoncastiblanco/notes-grpc

Comment: This doesn't work, I still get strange id errors. There is also a lot of gRPC stuff I don't use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too little too late, but the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210395/how-to-setup-protobuf-in-kotlin-android-studio) worked for me using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1--with the exception of the protobuf section. I had to change it from:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.20.1"
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            java {
                option 'lite'
            }
            kotlin {
                option 'lite'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.20.1"
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
                kotlin {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the subtle difference in the `generateProtoTasks`. Just make sure you drop your .proto file into `/src/main/proto` in your project and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that your sourceSets is actually within the android brackets:

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    main {
      proto {
        ...
      }
      java {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```